# How to open kendo grid hyper link column in new tab?

Tags: javascript

I have a grid which contains some columns. In that column one of the column is hyper link column. If I click the hyper link column the URL should open in new tab instead of current tab.

[image]

```
{
    field: "CumulativeGrossUSD",
    title: dashBoardColumNames[0].CumeGrossUSD,                     
    format: "{0:n0}",
    type: "number",
    template: '<a class="titlehyperLink" style="color:blue"  id="cumeTemplate">${kendo.toString(CumulativeGrossUSD, "n0")}</a>',
    attributes: { style: "font-size: 0.85em;text-align:right" },
    width: 120,
}
```

The function for `titlehyperLink` is:

```
$("#gridid").on("click", "#cumeTemplate", function (e) {           
        window.location.href = "/International/TerritoryTitleList?TitleId=" + dataItem.TitleId;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `window.location.href` try this:

```
var url = "/International/TerritoryTitleList?TitleId=" + dataItem.TitleId;
window.open(url,'_blank');
```